# Filter queryset by checking two columns if they are equal

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    paid = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get all entries that have paid and price columns the same value.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for this

```
from django.db.models import F

Entry.objects.filter(price=F('paid'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 12
Entry.objects.get(paid=x, price=x)
```

Does this solve your problem??

Comment: No, I just wanted to check if they are equal with each other, not if they both have a specific value. Check my solution below

Comment: Alright... Good you found the F method.